# Access a previous sibling element using RelativeSource binding (not ElementName) in WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, relativesource

I am trying to access a property of a sibling element that comes directly BEFORE the target element. This is something I will have to duplicate several times in my app so I'd rather use something reproduceable (not elementName) if possible.

Any Ideas?

```
<Groupbox x:Name="GB1">

  <Checkbox x:Name="CB1" IsChecked="True"/>

  <TextBlock>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Style.Triggers>

        <Data.Trigger Binding RelativeSource={??? (I want this to access the Checkbox CB1 above), Path=IsChecked}" Value="True>
            <Setter Property="*Do a Thing if IsChecked=True*" Value="..."/>

      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBlock>
</Groupbox>
```

Comment: We don't know the binding source of your case but in some scenarios, you can use `RelativeSource.PreviousData`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/relativesource-markupextension

Comment: You should explain what your app does in more detail.  We have to guess at the moment which does not bode well for your question.  How would someone reproduce whatever you're looking at ( but not showing us ) in order to prove their code worked?

Comment: It looks like you want pairs checkbox, textblock. I would suggest you to create a usercontrol which has them as content. So you can easy use ElementName binding and reuse the usercontrol without need to generate the names each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this example will give you an idea.

```
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="Text" />
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Text="Text">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=Children[0].Text}"/>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

`Path=Children[0].Text` it will look for the first child element of this ancestor and access its Text property.